# Making an Excel lookup marco flexible to cover different reference lengths

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have a macro which is searching 3 worksheets for an `invoice number` that a user might enter (in total over 2.6 million records).

The numbers come in a single cell which also has a look up reference in it. form: `invoicenumber, reference_letter`.

Originally, that was fine because `invoice numbers` were 10 digits. Now they can be anything, but there is always a comma at the end, before single char reference.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address <> "$A$5" Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

Range("B5") = ""

For Each sh In Sheets
    If sh.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then GoTo 111
    sh.Range("B1").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(MATCH(Main!A5,LEFT(A:A,10),0),"""")"
    If sh.Range("B1") <> "" Then
        x = sh.Range("B1")
        Range("B5") = Right(sh.Range("A" & x), 1)
        Exit For
    End If
111
Next sh

Application.EnableEvents = True

If x = "" Then MsgBox "Not Found!"

End Sub
```

I know that this 10 char restriction is in line 8, and I tried replacing with a `FIND`, but I don't think I had it right (on the basis that I couldn't get it to work!).

I'd be grateful for help in getting this sorted.

I have a further vLookup which is taking that last character and returning text from a separate sheet.

Comment: Use the `Instr` method to find the location of the comma.  Then subtract 1 and use that value for the number of characters in the `Left` function.  You may need to also `TRIM` if there are extra spaces.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I see what you are doing. How would code that into here then? I can't figure how to read the variable current cell: `instr (1,a:a, ',')` sure that a:a isn't right.

Comment: Sorry, it is in a formula on the worksheet (missed that):  You would use the `FIND` worksheet function to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim InvLen As Integer
If Target.Address <> "$A$5" Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("B5") = ""
    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then GoTo 111
        InvLen = Len(Worksheets("Main").Range("A5").value)
        sh.Range("B1").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(MATCH(Main!A5,LEFT(A:A," & InvLen & "),0),"""")"
        If sh.Range("B1") <> "" Then
            x = sh.Range("B1")
            Range("B5") = Right(sh.Range("A" & x), 1)
            Exit For
        End If
111
    Next sh
Application.EnableEvents = True
If x = "" Then MsgBox "Not Found!"
End Sub
```

Comment: It didn't work as a variable, but worked perfectly when I put it straight in:

Comment: `IFERROR(MATCH(Main!A5,LEFT(A:A,Len(Main!A5)),0),"""")"`